# Redirect by browser language, both in php and .htaccess gives error: Too many redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

So I have two languages available for my website, Dutch and German.
I've tried many different ways to redirect my website by browser language, yet they all give the error that my website is redirecting me too often: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I've tried it in php and with the .htaccess file.

My website needs to be redirected by the browsers language.
The Dutch version is in the root.
The German version is in the subfolder /de.
The Dutch version is also the default.

How can I redirect by browser language without any errors/problems?

Comment: Put the code of your trials so far

Comment: What exactly have you tried that resulted in the many redirects?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you **always** redirect to the DE version, meaning that you don't check if you're already on DE.

Make it so that you only redirect if your browser language is **DE** and your website version is **NL**.

```
if($browserLanguage === 'DE' && $browserVersion === 'NL')
{
    //Redirect to DE version
}
```

It's just a wild guess tho, since you didn't provide any code.